# Google App Engine custom domain won't release my domain name from DNS

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I set up Google App Engine with my custom domain while working on my certification.  www never worked as for some reason (I must have done something wrong) it was pointing to ghs.google.com.  I decided to try to fix it but, like an idiot but I'm claiming ignorance, I had already removed the TXT records from my DNS.  Google said that I wasn't authorized to make a change.  So, I decided to just remove the app engine from my project altogether.  I did that, deleted the project but now, my www is still in google's DNS, somehow.  Interestingly enough, now it's resolving to the appspot.com instance that it should have been resolving to all along.  I just want to get it out so that I can have it resolve via my DNS instead but it doesn't seem to want to cooperate.
Any suggestions as to what I can do to get my domain out of google's DNS. I guess, the issue is that google is serving as an SOA for my domain?  However, only the www.

Editing for clarity:
Sure.  I set up google app engine and used my domain example.com and set up ssl certs through google cloud app engine custom domain.  The naked domain (example.com) worked fine and I could get to my website.  The www (www.example.com) never worked.  Now I have finished with the lab, got my certs and closed out the project in google cloud that I was using.  When I ping my example.com I get the correct DNS resolution, however, when I ping www.example.com it resolves to XXXXXXXX.appspot.com so my www sub is still registered with google's DNS.  How do I get that to stop?  I have the www in my DNS as well, but apparently google's DNS is taking precedence over my DNS.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you please state question more specific, so that the answer can be very clear

Answer (score 0):

Your question in kind of confusing but I think the issue is with your configuration in your DNS.

App Engine does not configure your DNS never, actually who configures the DNS Records is you. App Engine only shows you which configuration should be [added](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains#dns_update) and this means App Engine cannot set the precedence over my DNS as this is managed always by the DNS.

My suggestion is to check the DNS records in your DNS, in particular those CNAME records that generally are related with non-naked domains (www.example.com, stack.example.com, etc) in App Engine.

Please note that deleting a project will not delete the mappings of custom domains in that project because you have 30 days to recover the project. My suggestion is to [recover](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project) the project, delete the mappings from app engine and then you can safely delete the project again to avoid unnecessary costs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, I don't think that's entirely correct.  When I do an nslookup query against type=SOA, I get this.

appspot.com
        primary name server = ns1.google.com
        responsible mail addr = dns-admin.google.com
        serial  = 303073529
        refresh = 900 (15 mins)
        retry   = 900 (15 mins)
        expire  = 1800 (30 mins)
        default TTL = 60 (1 min)
when I query the naked domain using type=SOA it says that the primary name server is my DNS.

Comment: Fernando,     Thanks for the suggestion.  I think that part of the original problem is that I removed the TXT records that Google had me add after I verified that the domain was mine.  I can't find them and now it says that I am not authorized to manage the domain.  Is there a way to recover from that?

Comment: Actually the DNS servers are who manage at which site will be pointing (IP, CNAME), no App Engine. If you're doing a nslookup and you get that result, it means that you added those DNS in a configuration, not App Engine. Could you imagine that App Engine manages DNS servers for you? 

Now, if you are using Google Domains, by default the servers are the Google DNS servers but they use the records you're adding and that's why you can see "ns1.google.com".

Comment: Regarding the TXT record, if you remove it there is no issue. I've verified domains using the TXT records and after the verification I remove them as they are not necessary anymore and I can continue managing the domains. Where is the message that tells you that you can't manage the domain?

Comment: Fernando,   I get the message that I'm not authorized to manage the domains when I pull over any button in app engine to try to manage it (such as delete).  I assure you that I have nothing in my DNS pointing to google.  This has literally never worked and I thought that it would start working when I deleted the project but it didn't.

Comment: Now, what you can do is to verify the domain again to get the ownership and delete the mappings from App Engine. You can follow the steps described [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/verify-domain-name#verifying_ownership)

Comment: Fernando,   Hey!  I just realized that it was probably you that I talked to on the phone when I called.  I have re-verified the ownership, removed the mappings and the problem is still persisting.  I'm still working with the other tech support folks via email right now to see what the problem could be.  I'll post here when we get this resolved.  Still the www resolves to the .appspot.com address but the naked domain works fine again.  Thanks for the help.